# opam init fails on docker

Tags: docker, opam, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to install a simple *linux* environment with *opam* on *docker*:

```
$ type .\Dockerfile_Opam.txt
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN                        \
apt-get update -y       && \
apt-get install opam -y && \
opam init
```

Equivalent commands *work fine on native linux* but with docker I get an error:

```
$ docker build --tag host --file .\Dockerfile_Opam.txt .
# ... omitted for brevity ...
#5 48.09 [ERROR] Sandboxing is not working on your platform ubuntu:
#5 48.09         "~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build sh -c echo SUCCESS >$TMPDIR/opam-sandbox-check-out && cat $TMPDIR/opam-sandbox-check-out; rm -f $TMPDIR/opam-sandbox-check-out" exited with code 1 "bwrap: Creating new namespace failed: Operation not permitted"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPAM runs builds when installing packages. To guard against buggy makefiles (that might run `rm -rf /` by accident), OPAM uses bubblewrap to sandbox the builds. Either install bubblewrap (`apt-get install bubblewrap`) or, if you wish to skip, because you're running in a container anyway, initialize OPAM like this:

```
opam init --disable-sandboxing
```

Comment: As an aside, not directly related to OP: in WSL, bubblewrap is dysfunctional. So go the `--disable-sandboxing` route and be on your guard.

Comment: curious why did you do `apt` and not `apt-get`?

Comment: You are right. Definitely apt-get is preferable.

Comment: curious, why do we need `--disable-sandboxing`? why does that work?

Comment: fyi this also works:
```USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bubblewrap
RUN opam init``` but not sure if its good. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72649718/1601580

Comment: It is *either* install `bubblewrap` *or* disable sandboxing. The default for sandboxing is to be active, and that would not work without `bubblewrap`. The purpose of sandboxing is to protect the user's filesystem in case there is a bug in some package's build. Since I feel that a container is usually a one-off thing that does not hold data that can not otherwise be reproduced, I find it redundant to sandbox builds in Docker. But ofc you can do it if you like, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This also works but idk if its safe or the cons/pros with the disabling sandbox option:

```
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bubblewrap
RUN opam init
```