# How to use apt-get install in docker when there is a Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied) issue safely?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, opam

I want to run `opam init` in docker but get the error:

```
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ docker build -t brandojazz/pycoq:test_brando ~/pycoq/tutorial/
[+] Building 1.5s (12/19)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.33kB                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                                                                                                                                   0.2s
 => CACHED https://api.github.com/repos/IBM/pycoq/git/refs/heads/main                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [ 1/15] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:fd92c36d3cb9b1d027c4d2a72c6bf0125da82425fc2ca37c414d4f010180dc19                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/15] RUN apt-get update   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     ssh     git     m4     libgmp-dev     opam     wget     ca-certificates     rsync     strace                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/15] RUN useradd -m bot                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/15] WORKDIR /home/bot                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/15] RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh   && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/15] RUN conda create -n pycoq python=3.9 -y                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/15] ADD https://api.github.com/repos/IBM/pycoq/git/refs/heads/main version.json                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [ 8/15] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bubblewrap                                                                                                                                                     1.2s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 > [ 8/15] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bubblewrap:
#12 0.237 Reading package lists...
#12 1.118 E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
#12 1.118 E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bubblewrap]: exit code: 100
```

I am able to fix it with ([How to install new packages into non-root Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576928/how-to-install-new-packages-into-non-root-docker-container)):

```
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bubblewrap
RUN opam init
```

but unsure if that is the right way to solve this.

Is it?

Dockerfile up to that point:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ssh \
    git \
    m4 \
    libgmp-dev \
    opam \
    wget \
    ca-certificates \
    rsync \
    strace

RUN useradd -m bot
WORKDIR /home/bot
USER bot

RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
  && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f
ENV PATH="/home/bot/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
RUN conda create -n pycoq python=3.9 -y
# somehow this "works" but conda isn't fully aware of this. Fix later?
ENV PATH="/home/bot/miniconda3/envs/pycoq/bin:${PATH}"

ADD https://api.github.com/repos/IBM/pycoq/git/refs/heads/main version.json

# TODO: doesn't seem to work...try later perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123637/activate-conda-environment-in-docker
# TODO: if you run VP's image and attack a volume that seems enough for now.
# RUN conda init bash
# RUN echo "conda activate pycoq" > ~/.bashrc
# RUN conda activate pycoq
#RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda
#RUN conda install conda-build

# - setp up opam
#RUN conda install -c conda-forge opam
#USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bubblewrap
RUN opam init
```

Note I did try to run it as one command with apt-get update but it failed as suggested here [Apt-get not working within ubuntu dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749847/apt-get-not-working-within-ubuntu-dockerfile).

I also saw: [Docker apt-get update fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832972/docker-apt-get-update-fails) but didn't understand it.

Note this also works [opam init fails on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300291/opam-init-fails-on-docker#72303187)

```
opam init --disable-sandboxing
```

but unsure if that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue as you with a Dockerfile, permission issue with `apt`.  I did not have the `USER` line that you added in my original file, once I added it in the Dockerfile the `apt` ran without any problem.  I'm brand new to Docker so I can't tell you if your solution is the correct answer to not but I'm going to keep the `USER` line in my file until I'm told it's incorrect.  In my opinion, it makes sense because I use `sudo` at the command line to run `apt`.